# Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

i create a component for show for error in `shared.module.ts` .

```
<span *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName)">
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-1" role="alert" *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).required">
    پر کردن   {{nicename}}  اجباری است
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-1" role="alert" *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).touched">
    پر کردن   {{nicename}}  اجباری است
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-1" role="alert" *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).pattern">
    باید از کارکتر های فارسی استفاده شود
</div>
<div class="alert alert-danger mt-1" role="alert" *ngIf="fieldErrors(fieldName).minlength">
    تعداد کارکتر های مورد استفاده باید بیشتر از {{fieldErrors(fieldName).minlength.requiredLength}} باشد
</div>
```

**Ts**

```
    export class FilderrorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input("form") from:FormGroup
  @Input("field") fieldName:string;
  @Input("nicename") nicename:string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fieldErrors(field:string){
    let controlState=this.from.controls[field];
    return (controlState.dirty || controlState.touched) ? controlState.errors:null;
  }
```

and i use that in html file :

```
 <form [formGroup]="addCatFG" >
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">نام دسته</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" formControlName="name">
        <app-filderror [form]="addCatFG" fieldName="name" nicename="نام دسته"></app-filderror>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputState">زیر دسته</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control" formControlName="parentId">
          <option selected>دسته مورد نظر را انتخاب کنید</option>
          <option>دسته اصلی</option>
        </select>
        <app-filderror form="addCatFG" field="parentId" nicename="زیر دسته"></app-filderror>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and this is **TS**

```
      InitialForm()
  {
    this.addCatFG=this.fb.group({
      name:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      parentId:['',Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    })
  }
```

but when page is load show me this error :

> Cannot read property 'dirty' of undefined

and [this is my sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-utrvv2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform%2Fform.component.html)

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: try this `return controlState && (controlState.dirty || controlState.touched) ? controlState.errors:null;`

Comment: @NadhirFalta its not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `@Input("field") fieldName:string;` that means that input property `field` will be mapped to variable `fieldName`. But you used `fieldName="family"` as assignment. Change that to `field="family"`.

```
<app-filederror [form]="addCatFG"  field="family" nicename="family"></app-filederror>
```